# How can I have a repeating elements in a UWP Border?

Tags: uwp-xaml

I want to create a XAML Border that looks like the highlighted whammy border - [highlighted whammy](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-yNn3dNg7asU/Tu0JEWPVCnI/AAAAAAAAB-c/-v0hVd_0HBQ/s1600/press-your-luck-whammy.jpgml&psig=AOvVaw1vZm4FxweptjJKTpxVWHje&ust=1548129745322645). I have the basic Border written (code below) but am unsure how to change the BorderBrush so I can have the repeating lights around the border. Is there a way to do this with *UWP* XAML? Assuming I can't use a custom brush (and I haven't found an appropriate one), is there a way to use a Grid?

```
<Border
    BorderBrush="Gold"
    BorderThickness="{Binding ElementName=slide0, Path=(behaviors:CustomAttributesBehavior.BorderThickness)}"
    CornerRadius="{Binding ElementName=slide0, Path=(behaviors:CustomAttributesBehavior.BorderCornerRadius)}"
    Visibility="{Binding IsHighlighted, Mode=OneWay}"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

> how to change the BorderBrush so I can have the repeating lights around the border.

In short, you need to make a custom panel to achieve your requirement. You need to derive a custom class from the [Panel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227511) class and override the [MeasureOverride](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br208730) and [ArrangeOverride](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br208711) method. In the `MeasureOverride` and `ArrangeOverride` method, you could define your own logic to measure and arrange the child elements.

Please check [XAML custom panels overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/layout/custom-panels-overview) and [BoxPanel, an example custom panel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/layout/boxpanel-example-custom-panel) for more details.

Here, according to your description, I've made a simple code sample for your reference. It's just my simple code sample. For your requirement, you need to do more calculations to layout the child elements.

```
class CustomPanel : Panel
{
    int ellipesHorizontalAlignmentTopCount, ellipesVerticalAlignmentleftCount, ellipesHorizontalAlignmentButtomCount, ellipesVerticalAlignmentrightCount;
    double ellipesHeigh = 20;
    double ellipesWidth = 20;
    SolidColorBrush ellipesColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LimeGreen);

    public CustomPanel()
    {
        this.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        double ex = 0;
        double ey =0;
        double imagex, imagey;
        foreach (UIElement child in Children)
        {
            if (child.GetType() == typeof(Ellipse))
            {

                if (ellipesHorizontalAlignmentTopCount>1)
                {
                    Point anchorPoint = new Point(ex, ey);
                    child.Arrange(new Rect(anchorPoint, child.DesiredSize));
                    ex += 40;
                    ellipesHorizontalAlignmentTopCount--;
                    continue;
                }
                if (ellipesVerticalAlignmentrightCount >1)
                {
                    Point anchorPoint = new Point(ex, ey);
                    child.Arrange(new Rect(anchorPoint, child.DesiredSize));
                    ey += 40;
                    ellipesVerticalAlignmentrightCount--;
                    continue;
                }
                if (ellipesHorizontalAlignmentButtomCount>1)
                {
                    Point anchorPoint = new Point(ex, ey);
                    child.Arrange(new Rect(anchorPoint, child.DesiredSize));
                    ex -= 40;
                    ellipesHorizontalAlignmentButtomCount--;
                    continue;
                }
                if (ellipesVerticalAlignmentleftCount>1)
                {
                    Point anchorPoint = new Point(ex, ey);
                    child.Arrange(new Rect(anchorPoint, child.DesiredSize));
                    ey -= 40;
                    ellipesVerticalAlignmentleftCount--;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                imagex = ellipesWidth;
                imagey = ellipesHeigh;
                Point anchorPoint = new Point(imagex, imagey);
                child.Arrange(new Rect(anchorPoint, child.DesiredSize));
            }


        }
        return finalSize;
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        ellipesHorizontalAlignmentTopCount=ellipesHorizontalAlignmentButtomCount = Convert.ToInt32(availableSize.Width / (ellipesWidth*2));
        ellipesVerticalAlignmentleftCount=ellipesVerticalAlignmentrightCount = Convert.ToInt32(availableSize.Height/ (ellipesWidth * 2));

        for (int i = 0; i < (ellipesVerticalAlignmentleftCount + ellipesHorizontalAlignmentButtomCount + ellipesVerticalAlignmentrightCount + ellipesHorizontalAlignmentTopCount); i++)
        {
            this.Children.Add(new Ellipse() { Fill = ellipesColor, Width = ellipesWidth, Height = ellipesHeigh });
        }

        foreach (UIElement child in Children)
        {
            if (child.GetType() == typeof(Image))
            {
                child.Measure(new Size(availableSize.Width - (ellipesWidth * 2), availableSize.Height - (ellipesWidth * 2)));
            }
            else
            {
                child.Measure(new Size(ellipesWidth,ellipesHeigh));
            }
        }
        return availableSize;
    }
}
```

```
<local:CustomPanel Height="300" Width="300">
        <Image Source="Assets/animals.jpg" >
        </Image>
</local:CustomPanel>
```

[image]